# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module with Node.js app deployment

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a node.js web application (cPanel on A2hosting) using source code I got from codecanyon. I keep getting this error (full log):

```
App 1418284 output: /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80
App 1418284 output:     return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
App 1418284 output:                         ^
App 1418284 output: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/watsbota/watshamfolder/server.js from /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js not supported.
App 1418284 output: Instead change the require of server.js in /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
App 1418284 output:     at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 1418284 output:     at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
App 1418284 output:     at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
App 1418284 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1) {
App 1418284 output:   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
App 1418284 output: }
App 1418284 output: Node.js v18.18.2
App 1419965 output: /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80
App 1419965 output:     return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
App 1419965 output:                         ^
App 1419965 output: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/watsbota/watshamfolder/server.js from /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js not supported.
App 1419965 output: Instead change the require of server.js in /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
App 1419965 output:     at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 1419965 output:     at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
App 1419965 output:     at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
App 1419965 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1) {
App 1419965 output:   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
App 1419965 output: }
App 1419965 output: Node.js v18.18.2
App 1422050 output: /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80
App 1422050 output:     return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
App 1422050 output:                         ^
App 1422050 output: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/watsbota/watshamfolder/server.js from /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js not supported.
App 1422050 output: Instead change the require of server.js in /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
App 1422050 output:     at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 1422050 output:     at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
App 1422050 output:     at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
App 1422050 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1) {
App 1422050 output:   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
App 1422050 output: }
App 1422050 output: Node.js v18.18.2
```

I'm new to this whole thing.